# How to get objects that contain a specific string

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I want to retrieve objects that contain a specific string in their CharField.
In normal Python without Django, I can do this to check:

```
if "something" in string:
   pass
```

However, I don't know how to do so using `.filter()` in Django:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(field = "string") # how can I do something like 'in' here?
```

I don't just want to get objects that have exactly the value as "string".

Please teach me how to retrieve objects that contain a specific string in Django using `.filter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains). This will do *case-sensitive containment test*.

```
Post.objects.filter(field__contains='string')
```

This will generate the following SQL query.

```
SELECT ... WHERE field LIKE '%string%'
```

See [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) for more information.

Comment: Or `icontains`. Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains

Answer (score 0):

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(field__icontains = "string")
```

Chack here [details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#icontains)

Comment: I'm fine with just `__contains`, but thank you anyways!

Comment: Yes this is your choice   __icontains it is Case-insensitive.